# How to prove that LU decomposition is unique?

Tags: matrices, matlab, lu-decomposition

given the following matrix how could I prove that LU decomposition of it is unique?

```
A=
1 3 1
2 9 2
1 3 1

L=
1 0 0
2 1 0
1 0 1

U=
1 3 1
0 3 0
0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2):

To prove it is easy. Suppose that
$$L_{1} U_{1}=L_{2} U_{2}$$
where $L_{1}, L_{2}$ are unit lower triangular and $U_{1}, U_{2}$ are upper triangular and invertible. (They must be invertible if $L_{i} U_{i}$ is so.) We now rearrange the equation to get
$$L_{2}^{-1} L_{1}=U_{2} U_{1}^{-1}$$
Now the left side is unit lower triangular and the right side is upper triangular, but only the identity matrix satisies both conditions at once. Therefore we have
$$L_{2}^{-1} L_{1}=I=U_{2} U_{1}^{-1}$$
hence
$$L_{1}=L_{2}, U_{1}=U_{2}$$
proving the desired uniqueness.

Comment: "Now the left side is unit lower triangular and the right side is upper triangular, but only the identity matrix satisfies both conditions at once." Wouldn't any diagonal matrix satisfy this? Why does it have to be the identity matrix?

Comment: It's diagonal in general but we constrained it to be a _unit_ lower triangular matrix as well.